# How can I fix Buttongroup Dropdowntoggle-Buttons in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I’m using Bootstrap 3 in my MVC-Project. In my _Layout page I’m using a buttongroup to do something like the example.

Example:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">MyButton</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(Surce: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_button_groups.asp)

**The issue is the button looks like this:**

[image: Screenshot of the Buttongroup]

How can I fix this?

**Edit**: I need a solution without using a CDN or downloading a custom Bootstrap CSS-File

Comment: Have you tried adding the attributes `aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"` to your `dropdown-toggle`-button as bootstrap docs say?

Comment: @Muli Makes no different, because it’s a css-issue

Comment: Then you should provide your CSS classes for insight. If you use the browsers' element inspector - what does it say concerning the styles of the button group? If you don't want to fully include bootstrap you have to adopt several Bootstrap-CSS Lines to your own CSS file or it won't ever display as it should

Comment: For sure, you override a Bootstrap class in your own CSS. Provide your CSS, so we can find what is going wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw it into a CDN and it was fine. So that means it is your CSS. I would try adjusting the padding and/or the height of the .dropdown-toggle

Comment: I wrote a fix class in my .less-file. It’s not the best way but shit happens ;)

Comment: I let the question open, maybe someone else find «the solution» form y issue.